# PHP echo <tag> content from the same page for breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, php, tags, echo, breadcrumbs

I am using the following script to create breadcrumbs, however it takes the same foldername as the name of the link.  Is there a way to echo the first 4 words for example from the title tag of the html page (`<title>Any written title here for the page</title>`) instead of the foldername?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var path = "";
var href = document.location.href;
var s = href.split("/");
for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+"</A> / ";
}
i=s.length-1;
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+"</A>";
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + path;
document.writeln(url);
</script>
```

So the link name would be instead of the foldername, it becomes `Any written title here...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `document.title` to get the title of the page.

So you can try something like this:

```
var path = "";
var href = document.location.href;
var s = href.split("/");
for (var i = 2; i < (s.length - 1); i++) {
    path += "<A HREF=\"" + href.substring(0, href.indexOf("/" + s[i]) + s[i].length + 1) + "/\">" + s[i] + "</A> / ";
}
i = s.length - 1;
path += "<A HREF=\"" + href.substring(0, href.indexOf(s[i]) + s[i].length) + "\">" + document.title.split(" ").slice(0, 4).join(" ") + "...</A>";
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + path;
document.writeln(url);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it divides the same page's title over the other links like: `Any / written / title / here`.  It should keep the other links the same foldername, but the last link should show the first four words of that document

Comment: Okay I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. See my updated answer

Comment: Also, would it be possible for the other links that takes the first 4 words of their titles? Or that needs an array in php or through database?

Comment: Yes, just replace `s[i]` by `s[i].slice(0,4)`, this is will print only the first 4 letters

Comment: Sorry, i meant 4 words of their `<title>` tag, not foldername. (for the rest of the paths). not the same file.

Comment: Ah yes that would be a bit more complicated. Ideally you would need a database with all pages linked to each other. But a quick and dirty solution would be to do an AJAX request for every path in the current breadcrumb, grab the title and display the first 4 words. Not very optimal though...